# Providing context in Class name, even though the namespace provides context

Tags: c#, .net, naming, clean-code

So I am reading *Clean Code* and I want to write my class names with the proper amount of context, but how does .NET namespaces play into the concept of *Meaningful Names*?

Do I forego context in the class name that has been provided in the namespace?

For example, If I have the following namespaces

```
MySolution.Event.Registration.BeginRequest  
MySolution.Event.Registration.EndRequest  
MySolution.Event.Registration.Error
```

Should I name the classes EventRegistrationBeginRequest, etc.?

Comment: Related reading: [.Net Framework Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Will the namespace context be visible in code that uses these classes? E.g. do you expect to always see `MySolution.Event.Registration.BeginRequest`, or would users import that class name and write `BeginRequest`? In my experience, it's usually the latter – thus indicating that each class name should provide enough context in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid classes with identical names, even if the name spaces differ.

The problem is, you import and forget about the namespaces and it becomes unclear which class is meant to be used.

Refactoring can be a nightmare of you move the class to a different project.

I would also not recommend the 'clean coding' BigLongClassNameOfDeath either. Try and keep your names specific to your functionality, avoid public Request, Response, Error etc, or at least move them to a common library